# How to Destroy All Session With Exceptional in Codeigniter?

Tags: session, codeigniter

In my code, I have logout function as below

```
function logout() 
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();  

    // but, don't destroy this session
    $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
}
```

How to destroy all session, except 'admin_id'?

Comment: I don't get if you're trying to destroy all sessions besides the admin's or if you're trying to destroy all the admin's session data but not his id.

Answer (score 3):

The Session destroy in CI is performed at the next request, so you can't destroy a session and  open a new session without a request in between.

But you could unset all session data except the data you like to keep and the data Codeigniter needs to keep the session. This Depends how session is configured, by default is it the User Agent, the last activity and the session ID. See [CI-Session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) preferences (at bottom of page)

This function deletes all session data except the admin_id

```
 $sessionData = $this->session->all_userdata();
 foreach($sessionData as $key =>$val){
    if($key!='session_id' 
       && $key!='last_activity' 
       && $key!='ip_address' 
       && $key!='user_agent' 
       && $key!='admin_id'){
         $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Must keep session_id, last_activity, ip_address, user_agent keys in order to have a valid session admin_id.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to save the admin_id temporarily and just put it back to session after you destroyed all your session vars.

```
$temp = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->session->set_userdata('admin_id', $temp);
```

Comment: it's not working because the session is not destroyed immediately but at next request.

Answer (score 1):

you must save some of keys in session, here is correct code.

```
$sess_array = $this->session->all_userdata();
foreach($sess_array as $key =>$val){
   if($key!='session_id'
      && $key!='last_activity'  
      && $key!='ip_address'  
      && $key!='user_agent'  
      && $key!='RESERVER_KEY_HERE')$this->session->unset_userdata($key);
}
```

This will work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

`$this->session->sess_destroy();` destroys the `session_id` and `last_activity` of the session. So the session no longer exist. So this wont work.

Try this:

```
$sess_array = $this->session->all_userdata();

foreach($sess_array as $key =>$val){

   if($key!='session_id'||$key!='last_activity'||$key!='admin_id'){
   $this->session->unset_userdata($key);
    }

  }
```

Comment: it's not working since your are destroying all keys using OR logic instead of AND logic